# Stackdriver URL wildcard

Tags: stackdriver

I'm using Google Cloud's StackDriver for tracing requests to my classical AppEngine rest server. Unfortunately, it handles request for URLs like:

```
/product/{id}
```

as a separate entry for each *id*, so I have, for example, statistics about each user separately. My code (REST backend in classical appengine) have about 10 endpoints, but StackDriver thinks I have millions, rendering it's analysis almost useless.

How do I make StackDriver correctly handle all URLs that use a given pattern (wildcards? regex?) as the same thing?